# Polymorphism with a vector of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, containers

there is many questions of these subject, but none allow me to solve my problem :

I have a template class and i want to store pointers of each derived class in a container (for example vector).
For this i created a base class like this :

```
class BaseTest
{
   //...
};
template <class T>
class Test : public BaseTest
{
    T testMethod(){...}
};
class DerivedTest : public Test<int>
{
   //...
};
```

Now i can have :

```
std::vector<BaseTest*> list;
list.emplace_back(new DerivedTest());
```

I would like to call

```
list[0].testMethod()
```

For this i must define the method `testMethod` in the class BaseTest but i think this is impossible because i want it to return the type `T` of the template class.

Maybe this is a conception problem but maybe someone have a solution ?
I hope I was understandable.

Comment: "this is impossible because i want it to return the type T of the template class" Correct, you'd have to find a "common denominator" type that can handle all possible return types, `std::any` for example. But rethinking the design is probably a better approach than such a massive code smell.

Comment: I closed as a dupe because I would have copy-pasted the answer otherwise. Tell me if the dupe is wrong or if there's something missing.

Comment: What would you *do* with the returned value?